# Finding inner product and expression for norm

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

We define the functions, $f_n$, $n=0,1,2,3,...,$ on $[-1,1]$ by
$$f_n(x)=x^n$$

Then I have to find the inner product for $\langle f_n,f_m \rangle$  for all values of $n, m$ and I have in particular, to show that:
$$||f_n||=(n+\frac{1}{2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

But I'm not sure how to do that? I'm confused, what is m? I think to show the norm I have to use $||f_n||=\sqrt{\langle f_n|f_n\rangle}$ ? But how do I find the inner product and use it finding the norm? I hope anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the standard $L^2$-inner product $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x)\, dx$, we have that
\begin{align*} 
\|f_n\|^2 = \langle f_n, f_n\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 x^{2n}\, dx = \frac{x^{2n + 1}}{2n + 1}\bigg|_{-1}^1 = \frac{2}{2n + 1} = \frac{1}{(n + 1/2)}. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice, that makes sense. But with the expression for $\langle f_n,f_m \rangle$ then be if for example n and m is different?

Comment: @Lifeni That is correct (:

Comment: Yeah but will the integral then be $\langle f_n,f_m \rangle=\int_{-1}^1x^nx^mdx$ or what will the expression for  $\langle f_n,f_m \rangle$ be when n and m are different?

Comment: @Lifeni It is exactly what you written down. You would then have to analyse different cases of $n$ and $m$. Since $n, m$ are both nonnegative, there is only two cases to consider: $n + m$ odd or $n + m$ even.

Comment: Nice, that makes sense. Thank you for the help :-)